# Sorting an already k-sorted array

Tags: algorithms, sorting, heaps

Can anybody give me some hint on how to do this? I'm not really sure where to start. The problem says:

> We say that an array $A[1...n]$ is $k$-sorted if it can be divided
>   into $k$ blocks, each of size $n/k$, such that the elements in each
>   block are larger than the elements in earlier blocks, and smaller than the elements in later
>   blocks. The elements within each block need not to be sorted. For
>   example, the following array is 4-sorted: $$1,2,4,3 | 7, 6, 5 | 10,11, 9, 12 | 15, 13, 16, 14$$
>
> a) Describe an algorithm that $k$-sorts an arbitrary array in time
>   $O(n\log k)$.
>
> b) Prove that any comparison-based $k$-sorting algorithm requires
>   $\Omega(n \log k)$ comparisons in the worst case.
>
> c) Describe an algorithm that completely sorts an already $k$-sorted
>   array in time $O(n \log(n/k))$.

Googling I found [this](https://www.coursehero.com/file/6218079/hw9sol/) paper with the solution of of a) and b), but I still don't fully understand how to solve this.

For a) my teacher said that we need to find the median and then do something like what quicksort does on finding a good pivot. I was searching over the net and I had the idea to put the $k$ first elements as leafs of a min-heap and then take the min element and with the next element of the array fill each block with $n/k$ elements, but it fails with the input: $8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1$

Clearly, b) is something like proving that any algorithm based in comparisons takes $O(n\log n)$. Maybe $\log k$ is because we only need to sort each block with $n/k$ elements, that means for each block we need to do $O(n/k \times\log k)$ $k$ times, so we could actually do it in time
 $O(k\times n/k \times \log k) = O(n\log k)$

For c) I'm not really sure, but I can take all the elements of each block and put them as leafs of a min-heap $-$ which gives $O(\log n/k)$ $-$ and then sort them, which I think would take $O(n \log n/k)$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea but I think you are overthinking it a bit.

For a), your teacher had a good hint.   I think there is a simpler solution than the way you are going. As a further hint, notice that if $k=2$, the problem is solved after 1 round of quicksort (with linear median-finding).  You have two equal-sized subarrays, where the left is smaller than the right.  Can you extend this to $k=4$?  Then, can you extend it to arbitary $k$?

b) I think you have the right intuition, but this argument is not formal yet.  Recall the original proof of the sorting lower bound, where you argue that you need $n\log n$ comparisons to get  $n!$ permutations.  Can you extend that to this case?  How many permutations are required when we don't need to fully sort?